# Deny access to youtube in a Wireless Hotspot created in PC - windows 7 using cmd

Tags: windows-7, proxy, hotspot, broadband

I have followed this tutorial to create a Wireless Hostspot using cmd in Windows 7: https://blogs.ncl.ac.uk/isg/?p=437

Now I want to deny access to Youtube for everyone who uses this Wireless hotspot using a proxy or something , because it losts a large band of connexion.. Any Help !!

Note : I'm using a mobile broadband to connect to the internet.

Thanks Before :)

Comment: Install a proxy server software on your computer that is bound to the hotspot device/connection and you can block whatever you need... An example software I've used before is Proxy+ but this site isn't a product recommendation service so you will have to research for yourself.

Comment: So i've to find a software that is bound to the wireless card of my computer.thank you for your answer

Comment: And does it do what you want - block YouTube for your clients? If so and it's completely answered your question I'll write it up as an answer for you to accept.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't .. All the proxy softwares i found are designed to a hotspot device such us a router.. my case is different , i'm sharing internet from my computer , using a mobile brodband.this is the problem.

Comment: I think what you're trying to do won't work because you're bridging your 3G to your hotspot and there's no gap to fit a third-party proxy server application to block the sites you want.

Comment: unfortunately , i also don't know if i can do so .. but i really need to do it .. anyway i thank u so much for helping

Comment: You may want to invest in a router (that will act as a hotspot and router/DHCP etc.) that should have the ability for you to create a blacklist of URLs and achieve what you want.

Comment: this is exactly what i will do , thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the router configuration. But since you are using a mobile broadband connection (which I assume you are using a mobile broadband stick), I think you should check the software that comes with it. To use a VPN or proxy, you should configure each host to not access a particular website. Or you can configure a VPN to a router, so all hosts connected to it don't access that website. Even if you use browser addons or any other way, the case is the same. You can even install custom firewalls on your router, but that is not the case with you.
 
Some USB modems support configuration. So its recommended you check your carrier website for more information. 
Also what I find really useful is using a router to share your mobile connection, like [Dovado Routers](http://www.dovado.com/en/products)

Comment: And, by the way, here it's a list of all the possible options to block a certain website: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001480.htm

Comment: I think you've missed the OP's question detail... they've basically used Window "ICS" to share the existing 3G Internet (via some USB dongle) with the computer's wireless adapter (by means of the "hosted network" capability using Windows `netsh`). What the user wants to do is block any of the clients (who connect via the hosted wireless network) from accessing such sites as YouTube to prevent the 3G data allowance being saturated. Using a traditional router (so you share the Ethernet socket of the computer) would be best because you could then use the router's config to block the site.

Comment: I read the question, and I think I was very clear. You can do that type of configuration in a router or in the case of mobile USB dongle, using a 3G/4G router. Anyway, in this particular case, only with a USB dongle, it's impossible to do it.

Comment: Yes Guys you are right .. i've checked all of the possibilities you suggested except the router solution but i didn't succeed .. so the last and unique solution for my case is using a router to share the Ethernet socket of the computer and install a proxy on it , or just using the router's config to block the site.